# Verification of Proof for an Inequality Problem

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

Prove that

$$x^{1116} + x^6 + \dfrac{1}{x^6+1} \ge 1$$

Below is a short proof that I have attempted. Sorry if the image causes any inconvenience as it was the clearest way to display my proof (I am not able to write proper equations (such as fractions) here yet):

[image]

I don't know if my proof is convincing enough or if it is adequate. Hence, if anybody could look at it and possibly give me any suggestions on how to improve, it would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: As a very first thing I notice: GREAT organization. That is far more essential to good proof writing than most people realize. At a glance, this looks convincing, and also very clean. I initially thought of just taking the derivative and finding the absolute minimum value, but that is a nightmare compared to your very simple method. Nice!

Comment: Looks fine. Nice presentation.

Comment: Let $t=x^6$, then $x^{1116}+x^6+\frac{1}{x^6+1}=t^{186}+t+\frac{1}{t+1}$ for $t\geq 0.$

Comment: Looks good.  You're relying on the fact that even powers are non-negative, so perhaps that can be directly used after your simplification, rather than considering different cases.